# Retrieve used groovy variable after evaluate

Tags: java, shell, dictionary, groovy

I'm using groovy like an evaluator/compilator from my java application. 
For example, I set a variable via the groovy binding (HS1 = 1, HS2 = 5)

```
binding.setVariable("HS1", 1);
binding.setVariable("HS2", 5);
```

and I launch an operation and catch the result via the groovy evaluate method( HS3 = HS1 + HS2)

```
value = (Number) shell.evaluate("HS3=HS1+HS2");
```

For my application, I would like to retrieve the used variable during my last operation (HS1 and HS2 in this case). I'm trying to use the binding.getVariables() method but it returns all the groovy session variable and not the last used variable.

Have you an idea to do that?

ps: Not easy to explain that with my french english level

Answer (score 0):

You need retrieve the value  with binding

```
    @org.junit.Test
public void test(){
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.setVariable("HS1", 1);
    binding.setVariable("HS2", 5);
  //binding.setVariable("HS3", new Integer()); 
    GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell(binding);
    binding.beginCut(new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>());
    Object o  = gs.evaluate("HS3=HS1+HS2");
    logger.info("GroovyTest.test: end cut");
    logger.info("GroovyTest.test: "+o);
    Map<String, Object> properties = binding.endCut();
    logger.info("GroovyTest.test: ------");
    for (Object v : properties.keySet()){
        logger.info("GroovyTest.test: "+v);
    }
    Number sResult = (Number)binding.getVariable( "HS3" ) ;
    logger.info(sResult);
}



 public class MyBinding extends Binding {
private static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger
        .getLogger(MyBinding.class);

@Override
public Object getVariable(String name) {
    logger.info("MyBinding.getVariable: request " + name);
    Object value = super.getVariable(name);
    //filter the requested variable
    if (properties != null) {
        properties.put(name, value);
    }
    return value;
}

Map<String, Object> properties = null;

public void beginCut(Map<String, Object> properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
}

public Map<String, Object> endCut() {
    Map<String, Object> properties = this.properties;
    this.properties = null;
    return properties;
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for your answer but I need to retrieve the variable used (HS1, HS2) and not the result (6).

Comment: @dolcichristophe i am update my answer, i think that is not a best way but maybe can resolve your problem.